# I can not find a local file from my application, by sending the filename in a post request. How do I find the file?

Tags: python, rest, api, directory, os.path

I'm creating a REST API (using FastAPI) and in my project has a local folder containing images, and I should send the name of the photo in a POST request to access it in a method I created.

The problem is that when I send the photo name to POST, it does not find the file in my application.

How can I find the photo so I can use it?

I'm using a relative path (dirname and abspath from os.path), but it's not working.

Folder structure:

```
.
├── app/
│   └── main.py
├── public/
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   └── 3.png
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── .gitignore
└── requirements.txt
```

main.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
import io
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join
from PIL import Image

dirname = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
images_path = join(dirname, '/public/')

def read_byte_img(image_path):
  img = Image.open(image_path, mode='r')
  imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
  img.save(imgByteArr, format='PNG')
  return imgByteArr

@app.post("/test")
def test(image_name: str):
  image_name = image_name + '.png'
  img = images_path + image_name
  byte_img = read_byte_img(img)
  return SONResponse({'response': str(byte_img)})
```

I tried to send the POST:

`localhost/analyze?image_name=1`

And the answer was:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/public/1.png'`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass arguments to `os.path.join`, if the second argument is an absolute path (has `/` at the beginning), then it returns the second argument.

`images_path = join(dirname, '/public/')` should be changed to `images_path = join(dirname, 'public/')`.

Comment: I changed to `images_path = join (dirname, 'public /')` but the error was the same. It looks like the / is at the beginning by default

Comment: Strange, could you print `images_path`?

Comment: Could you remove the space in `'public /'` and see if it works?

Comment: The path is without space. I think the space came when I pasted it here in StackOverflow. Too strange

Comment: Could you tell me what you see when you add `print(images_path)`?

Comment: I tested running the api without docker and it works perfectly. When I run the application with docker and make the POST request, the 'file not found' error occurs

Comment: Could you see if it works if you set `images_path` to `../public/`?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to ask these questions in the GitHub issues: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues, that way I (or others) can see your question and help you.

In this case, I see you have a `docker-compose.yml` file. So, first, check that you have the `public` files mounted as a volume in your container or that it's created.

To check it, you can use `docker exec -it your-container bash`, and then navigate to the directory and see where are your files.